# Get value from Db and set to @Html.TextBoxFor( ) Razor Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to Asp.net MVC and Razor. I want to show value from DB to text field value using Razor.
I have following code in **Controller**

```
public ActionResult edit(int id) 
    {

        using (var context = new pmcontext())
        {



          var user_1 = from u in context.Users
                            where u.UserID==11
                            select u;           
              ViewBag.users = user_1.ToList();

            return View();

       }
}
```

**In view i have**

```
 @model pm.Models.User
 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "edit";
 }

 <h2>Update User</h2>
 @foreach (var user in ViewBag.Users)
 {
      <p><b> User Full Name: @user.fullname </b></p>
      using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
      {


 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Name </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fullname, new { Class = "form-control", value=user.fullname }) </div>
</div>

      }
   }
```

I have also tried following in view to show user.fullname value in text box but failed to do so.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fullname, new { Class = "form-control", value="@user.fullname" })
```

Comment: The code in your controller generates a collection of `User` but the model in the view expects a single `User`. Its unclear what you really want to display in the view. I suspect you want `return View(user_1.FirstOrDefault();` (and delete the `ViewBag` property)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be:

```
using (var context = new pmcontext())
{
   //here how you can pass strongly typed model to View
   ViewData.Model = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == 11).ToList();
   return View();
}
```

Then in your View Change your model:

```
 @model IList<pm.Models.User> @*this is your actual model*@
 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "edit";
 }

 <h2>Update User</h2>
 @foreach (var user in Model)
 {
      <p><b> User Full Name: @user.fullname </b></p>
      using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
      {


 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Name </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fullname, new { @class = "form-control"}) </div>
</div>

      }
   }
```

I change Model, escape `class` in your `htmlAttrubutes` and get rid of `value=user.fullname` you don't need it since `TextBoxFor` get this value from your model property.

But note, that this way you will broke binding and it won't allow you to `POST` model right way.

The easies way to make everything right is to use `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
 {
      <p><b> User Full Name: @Model[i].fullname </b></p>
      using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
      {


 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Name </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].fullname, new { @class = "form-control"}) </div>
</div>

      }
   }
```

That will produce right `name` attributes to your `input`'s and binding will work right on `POST`.

Comment: Its unlikely there will be more that one `User` with `UserID == 11` so I suspect OP really wants to return just one `User` to the view (using `.FirstOrDefault()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke could be, but i don't get why he need a loop in a View then?

Comment: @StephenMuecke anyway, it will work even List have only one element =)

Comment: I know - the comment was more for the benefit of OP

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller**

```
public ActionResult edit(int id) 
    {

        using (var context = new pmcontext())
        {

          List<User> user_1= context.Users.where(x=>x.UserID==1).ToList();

          return View(user_1);

       }
}
```

Comment: `user_1` is a `IEnumerable<User>` so this will throw an exception (the view expects a single `User`)

Answer (score -1):

public ActionResult edit(int id)
        {

```
        using (var context = new pmcontext())
        {



            var user_1 = (from u in context.Users
                         where u.UserID == 11
                         select u).ToList();
            ViewBag.users = user_1;
            //make your Model type class object 
            User model = new User();
            model.fullname = user_1.fullname;

            ///Pass  your Model type class object On View.
            return View(model);

        }


    }
```

Comment: `user_1` is `IEnumerable<User>` which does not contain a property `fullname` so `model.fullname = user_1.fullname;` throws an exception

Comment: @model.fullname=@user.fullname  try its on your razor pages in for each loop.